# Thumbnail creation with symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, thumbnails

I'm trying to upload and save an image with a thumbnail.

The image itself is a `jpg` with a size of `2481 wide` and `3508 high`

I'm using the following plugin [sfImageTransformPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfImageTransformPlugin) and the following code:

```
$img->resize ( 150, null );
```

The problem is, when it saves, the image is:

`150 wide` and `3508 high`.

I thought the `null` parameter means it will keep the aspect ratio and resize accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `resizeSimple` instead:

```
$img->resizeSimple(150, null);
```